# Android Service that run every minute even if my application is closed

Tags: java, android

I build an application that manage a database of messages and show them to the user, i have a service that basically connect to web server and asks for updates.
I need that service to run every minute even if the application is closed.

so far i wrote the following code:

```
    protected void registerAlarm() {
    Intent getUpdatesService = new Intent(this, UpdatesService.class);


    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, getUpdatesService, 0);

    long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    firstTime += 60 * 1000;

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstTime, 60 * 1000, sender);
}
```

I call registerAlarm() from an activity that shows the messages.
That suppose to use AlarmManager to run the service evry minute but it doesn't work.
can anyone help me solve the problem?

Comment: Why not just create a service and then return START_STICKY to keep it running and started even when your app is killed?

Answer (score 1):

> I need that service to run every minute even if the application is closed.

That will not be practical on Android 6.0 and higher.

> can anyone help me solve the problem?

Tactically, your problem is that you are using `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` and `RTC_WAKEUP`. Those do not match. Use `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`.

However:

- Your app will not get control every minute on Android 6.0+, unless perhaps the user adds your app to the battery optimization whitelist in Settings
- `AlarmManager` does not work at all in some environments, notably the current developer preview of Android apps on Chrome OS (though for all I know this is a bug)

Comment: thank you, is there any practical way to run my service every one minute on Android 6.0+?

Comment: @omrydarwish: Only if the user adds you to the battery optimization whitelist, and perhaps not even then.

Answer (score 0):

You should use IntentService instead of Service because it automatically terminates after work is done plus it run on background thread